# About python3.6 when I import bs4, it doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-3.6

I import bs4 as:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

but it throws an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/koudai232/Desktop/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry, ParserRejectedMarkup
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bs4/builder/__init__.py", line 308, in <module>
    from . import _htmlparser
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from html.parser import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTMLParseError'
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['/usr/local/bin/python3', '-u', '/Users/koudai232/Desktop/test.py']]
[dir: /Users/koudai232/Desktop]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

But it works in python2.7.
I update my bs4 as :

```
pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4
```

It doesn't work yet.

How to solve this problem ,thanks~!

Comment: Check this [Beautiful Soup Documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#problems-after-installation)

Comment: Try pip for Python3: `pip3 install --upgrade beautifulsoup4`

Comment: I installed python3.6 by brew , and I find the latest version of bs4: bs4.5.3, I installed and replaced the former version bs4,but it still crashed as before .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should upgrade your beautifulsoup module to be fine with python 3.6.
Starting with 4.4.0, `BeautifulSoup` is compatible with Python 3.5. and above

`pip3 install --upgrade beautifulsoup4`

Comment: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/4.5/?C=M;O=A     thanks,but  I download the latest version and installed both python3 and python2 , it doesn't work , I don't know why...

Comment: Go to /usr/local/lib/python3.6/Scripts run pip uninstall beautifulsoup4 then install again. But important you should do this in right directory

Comment: wonderful!   I take your method  and delete old files then installed again. Finally, it worked correctly，thank you all.